# Yandex map CustomControl

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, как к [этому примеру](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control) прикрутить подписку на событие, например клик по кастомному контролу?
Можно конечно в HTML написать, но это не подходит.

Пытался так:

```js
  var customControl = new CustomControlClass();

  customControl.events.add('click', function() {
    alert('click on custom control');
  });

  map.controls.add(customControl);
```

не выходит.

Я пытаюсь создать `<input type="search"/>` контрол, нужно, что бы при выборе элемента фильтровались точки на карте. Использовать ListBox не вариант, ибо элементов 191 шт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно обратиться непосредственно к получившемуся DOM-элементу, например

```
document.getElementsByClassName('customControl')[0]
```

и привязывать обработчик к нему.